# Installing libmagic-dev on Amazon AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, amazon-web-services

When I want to install apt-get install libmagic-dev on my AWS machine, I have this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libmagic-dev : Depends: libmagic1 (= 1:5.14-2ubuntu3.3) but 1:5.14-2ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
redis-server : Depends: redis-tools (= 2:2.8.4-2) but 3:3.0.4-1chl1~trusty1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I type sudo apt-get -f install

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  redis-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  redis-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 275 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/333 kB of archives.
After this operation, 144 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] yes
(Reading database ... 69616 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../redis-server_3%3a3.0.4-1chl1~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
/etc/init.d/redis-server: 16: .: Can't open /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
invoke-rc.d: initscript redis-server, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/etc/init.d/redis-server: 16: .: Can't open /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
invoke-rc.d: initscript redis-server, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/redis-server_3%3a3.0.4-1chl1~trusty1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/redis-server missing LSB information
update-rc.d: see <http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts>
/etc/init.d/redis-server: 16: .: Can't open /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
invoke-rc.d: initscript redis-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/redis-server_3%3a3.0.4-1chl1~trusty1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It's a machine for Ruby on Rails project with redis-server. What I do wrong?

Comment: Reinstall redis-server fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this issue a month before. I give you a code which works for me.

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
```